# C++ template friend declaration for known class name nested in any other

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, friend

Good evening.

I have the following problem in writing some generic code (in C++11 at least):

Consider a class named `I` that may be nested in various classes A, B,...,N:

```
class A
{
protected:
  friend class I;
  class I
  {
  } i;
};

class B
{
protected:
  friend class I;
  class I
  {
  } i;
};

etc.
```

Actually `I` is a kind of interface tool, automatically inserted in various user classes A...N. Don't care of the reason to do that...

Then there is a specific class Z and the goal is to declare any `I` as friend of Z, so that any `I` and nothing else can use Z, whatever class A...N (defined later) the `I` will be nested in.

If I declare this way:

```
class Z
{
  friend class A;   // <--- but I don't want to have to know this one
  friend class I;
private:            // creation and use of Z are restricted to tools like I
  Z();
  // other methods
};
```

Then it works for `A::I` only:

From `A::I::some_function()` it is possible to build and use a Z,
but not from `B::I` nor any other in B...N.

Without the `friend class A;`, none of the `I` can access Z.

- How to get it generic ?

I'm looking for a way to write a template friend declaration granting the access for any `X::I` where X is the template parameter.

*And not a template parameter for `I` of course, since `I` is not a template.*

Of course I do not want to grant access to any class X so that any `X::I` can access Z too !

The following does not work:

```
class Z
{
  template< class X>  friend class X::I;
  ...
};
```

=> error: 'I' is not a member of 'X'
from gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)

Any idea of the correct syntax ? I did not find that use case in the reference...

Thanks a lot,
Kind regards.

================= added on Aug. 16 : Precisions:

The `I` exists durably as part of the `A` (or other) while the `Z` is a tool living only during a particular operation of the `I`, that may be repeated, then a new `Z` is created, used then deleted everytime as a local of a method of `I`.

Also the `Z` has a consequent payload and I don't want to make it a permanent part of every object embedding a `I`. For instance by making `Z` inherited by `I`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, any class that has a nested `I` type should be friends with `Z`? Without manually specifying these classes in `Z` you'd need reflection, which is not doable in c++ currently.

Comment: I made the 'I' bold so that they are more visible.

@cigien: No, it is only the 'I' inside any 'X' that must access 'Z', not the 'X' itself. I just want to declare 'I' friend of 'Z' through any outer class. Initially I expected it would work only with the name 'I', but apparently it does not, I get the error "Z() is private"

Comment: Just a short comment on your description: "Consider a class named I that may be nested in various classes A, B,...,N:" -- that doesn't describe it. There are multiple classes named `I`, nested in other classes. Their "full" name is `A::I`, `B::I` etc.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt : Yes, it is automatically inserted (short) code declaring a class always named `I` inside a user class, `I` being identical in its structure (not necessarily in the implementation of its methods) for all such user classes, then we could call it `*::I` in the present context. It is true that due to the path it is not the same C++ type, despite it is the same (terminal) identifier. This is why I expect to solve the problem with a template friend declaration enabling to vary the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve what you're trying to do by making `I` inherit `Z`, and make `Z` an abstract base class (so it can't be accessed directly).

Something similar to:

```
class Z
{
    virtual void __() = 0;
  public:
    virtual ~Z() = default;
    void method() { std::cout << "Method from Z" << std::endl; }
};

class A
{
    friend class I;
  
  public:
    class I : public Z
    {
        void __() final {}
      public:
        static Z *make_z();
    } i;
};

Z *A::I::make_z()
{
    return new I();
}

int main()
{
    Z *z = A::I::make_z();
    z->method();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it would cause terrible problems in terms of lifetime. The problem I posted is very simplified.

Actually the `I` exists durably as part of the `A` (or other) while the `Z` is a tool living only during a particular operation of the `I`, that may be repeated, then a new `Z` is created, used then deleted everytime as a local of a method of `I`.

Also the `Z` has a consequent payload and I don't want to make it a permanent part of every object embedding a `I`.

Sorry I cannot tell details in a comment and I'm not allowed to post a cleanly formatted answer to myself.